# Need additional space between chapter and leading section from PDF

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, pdf

I'm working on formatting my thesis in LaTex, and there are specific formatting requirements for the TOC. Let me warn you that I'm fairly inexperienced with LaTex, so forgive me for if there's pertinent information I leave off of this post. Essentially, I need double spaces between chapters, a double space between a chapter and the first section of that chapter, then single spacing for sections and subsections.

I used this to set up my TOC:

```
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft} % Treat the headers as titles
```

I used the following code to set up the spacing in the TOC:

```
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip1em} % Spacing of the TOC items
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip2pt} % Spacing of the TOC items
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip2pt} % Spacing of the TOC items
```

That gives me the appropriate spacing between the chapter heading and the first section, but it creates too large a space between chapters without sections, i.e., between the abstract and the list of figures. I was able to fix that by changing the \vskip for the chapter to 2pt and then adding an \ifnum statement from this website https://texblog.org/2013/07/16/how-to-add-extra-space-to-the-table-of-contents-list-of-figures-and-tables/.

That gave me this code, which will place a 10pt vskip where the section counter is 0.

```
\preto\section{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip10pt}\fi}
```

So, the skip is between the chapter title and the first section where I want it. This is great, because it also keeps the space between my abstract and list of figures, etc. to the right size.

My problem is that my second chapter is a republished paper that I'm reading in as a PDF. To get the sections from the paper into my bibliography (required by my thesis office), I used:

```
\includepdf[pagecommand={},
pages={1-},
addtotoc={
```

Then I populated the list with the appropriate sections and subsections. The trouble is that my code to prepend a space to the beginning of the leading section doesn't work for my second chapter. I can only imagine it has something to do with that chapter being a PDF and the first section was created by using addtotoc.

I've created a work around by inserting a "preamble" section in the chapter2 tex file, but I'd sure like to understand why the prepend statement doesn't work with those sections. Does anyone have any ideas what's going one here? It just occurred to me it's likely related to my package using the package I referenced earlier where headers are used to create the TOC. So, maybe my prepend statement is just looking for headers, and I'm guessing it doesn't read in things from addtotoc as headers. Regardless, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!